# injecting a build tool into eclipse cdt

Tags: build-automation, eclipse-cdt, auto-generate, xilinx, prebuild

I would like to convert my file into .h and then run the build. How do I do that (particularly, in Xilinx SDK 12.4, which says that it is eclipse Version: 3.5.1.R35x and cdt Version: 6.0.0.201005121341)?

Answer (score 0):

In the project properties, I have discovered `Settings -> Build Steps` where you can find a `pre-build steps` command. For instance, I have added `xxd -i ../src/homepage.html ../src/homepage.h` and

```
pre-build:
    -xxd -i ../src/homepage.html ../src/homepage.h
```

has appeared in the make file

The conversion is invoked every time anything is build, even though html was not changed. So far, it is not a big deal for me. But, it allows you to improve the answer.